# Android ICS: Default browser not respecting <meta> viewport tags

Tags: android, scaling, viewport, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, metatag

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the viewport tag on the Galaxy Nexus / Android 4 not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374611/why-is-the-viewport-tag-on-the-galaxy-nexus-android-4-not-working)

In our android webapp for tatgeting various screens of andorid deive, we use the following meta view port tag for scaling based on device viewport scale

```
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=high-dpi; width=device-width; minimum-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">
```

But in Android ICS version of device, above Meta tag has NO effect on the application. The UI appears to be zoomed out and the app loses functionality.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Solution here could help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9638039/343039

Answer (score 0):

Try using commas as delimiters rather than semicolons (and remove the last semicolon).