# Why is the viewport tag on the Galaxy Nexus / Android 4 not working?

Tags: android, resize, viewport

I'm working on a webApp that should resize to any screen size a device could have. On iOS and older android versions the viewport tag works fine. The picture on the screen is always resized to fit the screen.
(Like described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006509-SW19)
On the Galaxy Nexus (Android 4.0) it won't work. On the left and right side is about 20px space and I don't know why he does this.
My viewport tag looks like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

No matter what I change about the tag, the space is always there and the content doesn't fit to screen.
I've made a sample page to show you the effect: http://easyeve.w3y.de/link/index.html
If you open this link on an iPhone the content perfectly fits (you won't see anything yellow =  body) and the document width is 320px. On the Galaxy Nexus you will see yellow space and the document width is 360px (which is exactly half of the display resolution). This should be 320px too!
Do you have this problem too and is there a way to fix it?

Update: I've noticed the same Problem on Galaxy Note / Android 2.3.6
Therefore it's not an Android 4 issue. It has to do with the large screen size I guess..

Answer (score 4):

The very same issue here (Galaxy Nexus - Android 4.0.2), I am talking about **regular web page in the default browser**

Setting viewport meta **initial-scale less then 1 (zoom out) seems to be ignored by the browser**. Higher values than 1 (zoom-in) works fine.

There are settings in the browser (settings->advanced) where you can change things:

1. Default zoom - it makes difference, but it does not fix the issue
2. Auto-fit pages - in my case makes no difference

Everything seems to work just perfect in Chrome browser (beta at the moment), but that is **not** default browser for ICS / Galaxy Nexus.

**UPDATE (solution):**

Setting meta viewport "width=device-width" fails on Galaxy Nexus.
Setting **viewport "width=1280" works just great** (1280px is width of the screen of galaxy nexus).

Beware that setting "width=1280,user-scalable=no" breaks it again (you can zoom out even if there is user-scalable=no) :(

Comment: thank you for your answer but it doesn't work for me :(
I changed my viewport tag to **width=1280** but that just causes that my site is very big (like desktop view) but zoomed in to the left corner.. I've changed my code:
[link](http://easyeve.w3y.de/link/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something somewhat similar on a Galaxy Tab 2.  When setting up your WebSettings for the applcation, try setting webViewSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);  This will force Android to consider the viewport meta tag.  It was being ignored in the case of the Galaxy Tab 2 for my app and everything in the viewport was drawing incorrectly until I changed this.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up wrangling with this problem today.  My issue was a little bit more complex, because I had to deal with a Wordpress stylesheet (from another theme) in addition to the base CSS.  Chrome worked perfectly on my phone and tablet and the stock browser worked fine on the tablet, too.  However, the stock browser kept zooming out and showing me the desktop view.  There were no margins on either side, which was the correct behavior, but the browser should have removed the floats from my sidebar and content divs and zoomed in to the main content (I'm using @media queries).  As weird as it sounds, I actually fixed this by first setting the Zoom setting to Far, refreshing, and then resetting Zoom to Medium and refreshing.

I should point out that when I looked at your page's HTML and CSS, I noticed that you set a specific pixel width for your page div.  I'm pretty sure you need to use percentages for width instead.  For example, my centered content div has `margin: 0 auto;`, `min-width:320px;`, `max-width:900px;`, and `width:100%;`.

Comment: Thank you. You're right that it will probably work if I'd set all my widths to percentages, but that's not what I want. I don't want a liquid design..